# How would you only show suggestions based on an exact or partial match in React Mentions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I'm using React Mentions (http://effektif.github.io/react-mentions/ or https://github.com/effektif/react-mentions) in a project.

I have removed the trigger from the regular express in `/src/MentionsInput.jsx`

```
var _getTriggerRegex = function(trigger) {
  if (trigger instanceof RegExp) {
    return trigger;
  } else {
    var escapedTriggerChar = utils.escapeRegex(trigger);

    // first capture group is the part to be replaced on completion
    // second capture group is for extracting the search query
    return new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)(([^\\s]*))$");
  }
};
```

This now shows the suggestions after any text input.

How would I go about hiding/not rendering the suggestions render unless there was an exact match? For example, in [the example](http://effektif.github.io/react-mentions/examples), how would the suggestions only show once the string 'John' was entered?  It shouldn't show the suggesetions when 'Joh' is entered.

[image: Only show suggestions when 'John' is entered]

Am I right in thinking that it would involved passing values in to `/src/SuggestionsOverlay.jsx`?

```
render: function() {
    // do not show suggestions until there is some data
    if(this.countSuggestions() === 0) return null;

    return (
      <div className="suggestions" onMouseDown={this.props.onMouseDown}>
        <ul>{ this.renderSuggestions() }</ul>
      </div>
    );
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `data` prop you should provide a filtering function instead of an array. The function will be called with the query as the first parameter. So all you have to do is check your data source for exact matches and return those. If nothing is returned, the suggestions overlay will not show up.